# Which Chumash has the most meforshim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, books-generally, torah-study, pentateuch-chumash

What sefer (prob Mikraos Gedolos) has the most meforshim in it?

Comment: You can't just buy the one that has the most meforshim and expect to have everything, because the ones with less meforshim aren't necessarily a subset of the ones with more meforshim, for example the Zohar HaNigleh is only in Mikraot Gedolot HaBahir.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mean specifically Torah commentary? Otherwise, I bet that some editions of Talmud or Shulchan Aruch would be in the running, too.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if [Torah Shleimah](http://www.nehora.com/products/Torah-Sheleimah-%252d-Rabbi-Menachem-Kasher-%2812-vol.%29-----%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%99%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D.html) because it's more of an encyclopedia that doesn't separate the commentaries.

Otherwise, look at [SeforimCenter's Mikraot Gedolot category](http://www.seforimcenter.com/prodtype.asp?cookiecheck=yes&PT_ID=81&strPageHistory=cat) and compare for yourself -- there are different sets with different focuses. For example, there's Mikraot Gedolot HaBahir which includes Zohar Nigleh, there's a mikraot gedolot of commentaries by the Abir Yaakov, there's a mikraot gedolot of Chassidic masters, etc.

Comment: SeforimCenter link is broken

Comment: The Shulsinger has 60 perushim. Way more than any of the others listed. I recall hearing that the Warsaw edition had a lot but I can't find the exact number.

Comment: Rabbi Kasher and his son never finished the ironically titled Torah shleima.

Answer (score 6):

Not a physical book, but the [Bar Ilan Responsa program](http://www.responsa.co.il) has *dozens* of commentaries.

Answer (score 2):

I think the set of *chumashim* ‘[Torat Haim](https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/)’ has the most commentaries on the page, specifically classical ones critically edited. They include:

- R. Saadia Gaon
- Rabbeinu Hananel
- Rashi
- R. Dovid Kimhi
- Ibn Ezra
- Rashbam
- Hizkuni
- Ramban
- R. Meir of Rothenburg
- R. Ovadiah of Seforno
- Sefer Ha’Hinuch

Comment: There's a 10 volume edition from Pardes Publishing in 1951 that has 32 perushim on the entire Tanach, apparently from the talmidim of the Vilna Gaon.

Comment: @KfirShlomo published by *talmidim* of the VG in 1951 (!) or *perushim* of *talmidim* of the VG?

Comment: https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30133580880&searchurl=tn%3Dmikraot%2Bgedolot%26sortby%3D17

Comment: @KfirShlomo I see, though the 32 are def. not all “talmidim of the VG”; in fact, few can be considered so. Additionally, not all 32 are running commentaries on the Pentateuch itself. But, feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 1861 Warsaw edition has 32 commentaries. It would appear that these are not just on the Torah proper and also that any Mikraot Gedolot with 32 peirushim are based on the this edition.

מקראות גדולות עם ל"ב פירושים : הלא המה: תרגום אונקלוס,

תרגום ירושלמי,

תרגום למגלות

, תרגום שני לאסתר עם באור [מאת ר’ חיים פייבל ב"ר דוד זכריה]

, פירש"י שלם עם המראה מקומות,

אבן עזרא

, רמב"ן,

בעל הטורים כולו [מאת ר’ יעקב ב"ר אשר],

ספורנו,

תרגום יונתן,

מסורה גדולה,

מסורה קטנה,

רד"ק,

רלב"ג,

פירוש רבינו סעדיה גאון,

פי’ רבינו ישעיה,

כלי יקר,

חידושי מהרש"א,

אדרת אליהו,

מצודת דוד,

מצודת ציון יוסף לקח [מאת ר’ אליעזר אשכנזי],

אגרת שמואל,

לחם דמעה [שניהם מאת ר’ שמואל די אוזידה],

ספורנו לשה"ש [לשיר השירים] וקהלת,

מנחת שי [מאת ר’ ידידיה שלמה נורצי],

תולדות אהרן,

תולדות יעקב,

ביאור לגבולין ובנין הבית,

באור על יהושע ישעיה ודה"י מהגאון מווילנא,

וסדר הפטרות עם ביאור המלות.

ועוד הרבה מעלות וכללי המסורה והדקדוק.

---

Image:

[image]:

Comment: can you share a link where I could buy a mikraos gedolos that has 32 pirushim? I've been looking and can't seem to find any. (if you know a store that sells it and it's not online that would also be helpful). (chumash is good, but including nach (ie. tanach) would be even better)

Answer (score 0):

As far as English goes, check out Judaica Press
https://www.judaicapress.com/collections/torah-study

Each volume contains the Hebrew Chumash text and all the classical Mikraoth Gedoloth commentaries. The facing page contains a modern English translation with extensive translation of the Mikraoth Gedoloth commentary--including a translation of every Rashi, and explanations of Rashi based on Gur Aryeh and Mizrachi. Also featured is commentary from the Ramban, Sforno, Rashbam, Ibn Ezra, Ohr Hachayim, Keli Yakar, selections from Talmudic and Midrashic sources and numerous other commentaries never before translated.