# How does the content of the JPS English translation of Miqra'ot Gedolot differ from that of the Hebrew version?

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books, commentaries, translation

Because I am not yet fluent in Hebrew I am excited to learn that JPS is publishing an English translation of Miqra'ot Gedolot.  (So far they've done [Sh'mot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827608128), Vayikra, and Bamidbar.)  As noted in one of the Amazon reviews, a complete translation of MG would run to a much higher page count than what they've produced, so my question is how the content of this edition compares to that of the original.  One person told me that this edition removes repetition -- when one commentary quotes another they collapsed that.  Is that the only substantive change? Does the translation omit other material (and if so, what?)?

Comment: Don't know for sure without seeing it, but I would assume that they might skip Ohr haChaim, Kli Yakar, Aramaic targumim, supracommentaries, chizkuni, daas zekeinim.  Also many comments are difficult to understand if you don't understand Hebrew in the first place like grammer Rashis.

Comment: @YDK, many *Mikraot Gedolot* don't have the commentaries that you listed and this one doesn't claim to. See the link in my answer below (p. xiv) for a list of commentaries included in this version.

Comment: There is no canonical _mikraos g'dolos_ (see e.g. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3983 and its topmost comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Alx1rJsiDFAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=JPS%20Miqra%27ot%20Gedolot&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i8EhT7T_FIj20gHFvOiwCA&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=JPS%20Miqra%27ot%20Gedolot&f=false) (pp. xvii-xviii) for a list of what the JPS Miqra'ot Gedolot omits from their translation of the commentators, what they retain, and what they change from the originals.