# Is there any Mikras Gedolos in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash, english

Is there any Mikras Gedolos in English? I am interested in learning Meforshim on Chumash, and I wanted to know if there were any online or in a store.

Comment: Hello Yehuda, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! The works of the [Sefaria project](http://www.sefaria.org/) may interest you, as they translate the works that they put online (though I'm not sure if they have the complete set, with all the meforshim, on all of Chumash.....yet). Hope to see you around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're interested in buying meforshim individually (in which case they will come with many more editorial and elucidation notes), here's a few:

[Artscroll Rashi](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191147.html)

[Metsudah Sifsei Chachamim](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=9382&strPageHistory=cat&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=641)

[Artscroll Ramban](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422610503.html)

[Artscroll Seforno](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062686.html)

[Artscroll Baal HaTurim](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191338.html)

[Menucha Publishers Kli Yakar on Bereishis and Shemos](http://www.seforimcenter.com/prodtype.asp?cookiecheck=yes&PT_ID=696&strPageHistory=cat)

[Urim Ohr HaChaim](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=946)

I didn't shop around for which websites would be the cheapest, so I'm sure you could find better deals.

Answer (score 5):

JPS is publishing an English edition.  I asked about its contents [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13635/472); it's a condensed version, but at one volume per book of torah it covers a lot more ground than a one-volume chumash.  I'm very happy with the volume I've used and plan to add the rest to my library.  Sh'mot, Vayikra, and B'midbar have been released; D'varim is due in April 2015, and I guess B'reishit will follow that.

Answer (score 4):

Judaica Press publishes a set of 
[Mikraos Gedolos](http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/bereishis-genesis-vol-2-judaica-press-mikraos-gedolos-series.html) with a digest of the commentaries in English.

Comment: I know the author, Rabbi Rosenberg. He did artscroll's mishnayos too. He's a holy Jew.

Comment: Not author. Translator:)

Comment: I have used volumes from this series in studying Nach, and have found the English digest to be quite valuable. If there was an issue I was interested in investigating, the digest helped me quickly determine which commentators, if any, addressed that issue, giving me both an overview of the issue and pointers for further study. The presence of the same commentaries right there, in the original Hebrew, helped the deeper study flow easily from scanning things in the digest. I liked these books so much, I resolved to buy the whole set (*beli neder*) the next time I'm ready to splurge on *sefarim*.