# Where can I get English commentaries on the Nach?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, navi-prophets, english

I was looking for English books containing full commentaries on Nach (such Ibn Ezra, Redak, Mesudat David/Tsion, Malbim, Abravanel and others). I am familiar with A. J. Rosenberg translation of Mikraot Gedolot, but I'm referring to full individual translations, like the ones published of David Kimchi on Isaiah ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593336756)) and Zechariah ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064C5684)); or even Rashi ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827608721)) and Hirsch ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598260456)) on Psalms.

I was wondering if there are other classic commentaries in English such
the mentioned above. Are there others available in a store? - (Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48735) question.)

Comment: Related (Chumash, not Nach): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48735/5323

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=8BJbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=yeshayahu+ibn+ezra+english&source=bl&ots=DHyaI2q96y&sig=mmBh5fIsPnLswLMebUn2sSbFm7E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VSjAVL7pLofEgwSJs4CoAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=yeshayahu%20ibn%20ezra%20english&f=false

Comment: I have Meam Loez series which covers a lot of Nach.

Comment: @AniYodea Neither of your links help; the first is only Chumash, while the second doesn't translate commentaries (though they do cite one on occasion).

Comment: @Shokhet, That's the wrong link, I meant the *Rubin* edition of the prophets: http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193318.html - it has more commentaries on the nach than the green stone edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to your references, here are some others. Feel free to add to this list.

### Rashi

- [Five Megillot](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=91&P_ID=979&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=268)
- [Tehillim](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=5433&strPageHistory=cat&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=150)

### Ibn Ezra

- [Tehillim (1-41)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193484330X)
- [Isaiah](https://archive.org/details/commentaryofibne03ibne)
- [Proverbs](https://archive.org/details/commentaryonbook00ibne)

### Saadia Gaon

- [Iyov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300037430)

### Ramban

- [Discourse on Kohelet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607630206)

### Midrash Rabbah

- [Soncino's Five Megillot](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=1122&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=290)
- [Artscroll's Five Megillot](http://artscroll.com/Items.aspx?hierId=MRB)

### Targum

- [Joshua, Judges, Samuel, and Kings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654797)
- [Isaiah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654800)
- [Ezekiel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654827)
- [Song of Songs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654533)
- [Iyov, Proverbs, and Kohelet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654908)
- [Ruth and Chronicles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081465455X)
- [Psalms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654916)
- [Jeremiah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654819)
- [Minor Prophets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814654894)

### Malbim

- [Iyov](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=91&P_ID=6366&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=268)
- [Mishlei](http://www.feldheim.com/malbim-on-mishley.html)

### Alsheich

- [Ruth](http://www.feldheim.com/a-harvest-of-majesty.html)

### Vilna Gaon

- [Yonah (adapted from his *Aderet Eliyahu*)](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191604.html)

### Hirsch

- [Mishlei](http://www.feldheim.com/from-the-wisdom-of-mishle.html)

### Dubner Maggid

- [Megillot (except Mishlei)](http://www.feldheim.com/authors/dubner-maggid.html)

### Torah Temimah

- [Ruth](http://www.feldheim.com/the-essential-torah-temimah-megillas-ruth.html)
- [Eichah](http://www.feldheim.com/the-essential-torah-temimah-megillas-eichah.html)

Answer (score 3):

Torah Anthology: commentaries from [Meam Lo'ez](http://www.mysefer.com/prodtype.asp?cookiecheck=yes&PT_ID=75&):

I have much of this series.