# English Translations of Major Yechezkel/Ezekiel Commentaries

Tags: rabbis, commentaries, navi-prophets, ezekiel--the-book

Shalom!

I have been looking for some time and I cannot seem to find any resources in English.  Are there any translations (into English) of the Yechezkel/Ezekiel commentaries of the following rabbis?

-Radak

-Malbim

-Isaac Abarbanel

-Joseph Hayyun

-Metzudat David

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Sefaria.org is working on translations of lots of stuff. Check whether any of these are already there. (I haven't.)

Comment: Helpful[ related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52988)

Comment: Al Hatorah is also working on translations for these https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Yechezkel/1.1#e0n6