# Midrash digest in English on the Web?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, midrash, commentaries, adult-learning

Where on the Internet might it be possible to find a summary of the most important midrashim (aggadot) for each parshah in English? Something like [The Midrash Says](http://www.judaica-world.com/the-midrash-says-set.html) but online. Even less thorough, eg from a kiruv website, is fine, too.

Related: [Is there any Mikras Gedolos in English?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48735/is-there-any-mikras-gedolos-in-english)

Comment: Define “most important.”

Comment: I wouldn't call this a recommendation, but "The Legends of the Jews" by Louis Ginzberg volumes 1-4 is available on Project Gutenberg in English.

Comment: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=midrash

Comment: @DonielF I think she intends to say the "most common" midrashim discussed by people when talking about the parshas hashavua.

Comment: Rashi seems to reference and summarize the common midrashim. Do you read Rashi every week with the parsha?

Comment: @ezra That’s what I thought, too. Yet she gives *The Midrash Says* as an example - that goes a *lot* deeper than Rashi.

Comment: @DonielF Yes, it certainly does. What I wonder is why it needs to be davka on the internet.

Comment: @ezra I can think of several offline sources as well. I won’t judge - if this is what the request is, then that’s what she’s looking for.

Comment: @ezra Usually, yes. But Rashi is usually (ok, hedge that a little) just pshat and you miss the aggadot that everyone knows. For example, the women cutting their hands while cutting the esrog (Vayeishev) and others like that

Comment: @ezra Davke on the Internet bc it's convenient

Comment: I found this which is close to what I want: https://archive.org/stream/cu31924029282849#page/n11/mode/2up However, I find the format cumbersome. Looking for something more like a website

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks for your suggestion; I like it a lot. I wish it were organized by parshah and were a little more, um, short, but I guess I'm being picky.

Comment: @SAH You’re welcome. Spread the light...Hanukkah sameach!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty good:

http://www.chabad.org/parshah/in-depth/default_cdo/aid/35803/jewish/Shemot-In-Depth.htm

"A condensation of the weekly Torah portion alongside select commentaries culled from the Midrash, Talmud, Chassidic masters, and the broad corpus of Jewish scholarship."

Answer (score 0):

[Legends of the Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_the_Jews), the seminal collection of midrashim by [Louis Ginzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg),  is available online in English. The advantage of this work is that it culls midrashim from various sources and presents them as one unified continuous story. It can be accessed [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/loj/index.htm).

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Nice!

Comment: One of many things... I'm not sure which leisure learning is a better use of my time.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות לעולם ילמוד אדם תורה במקום שלבו חפץ

Comment: :) Thanks!!!!!!