# need help finding online midrash sources about the story of exodus?

Tags: product-recommendation, midrash, commentaries, pharaoh, exodus

I need to find online midrash sources (in English ,and can be searched using key words ) that explain the whole or most of the story of Moses and the pharaoh...

Thanx all.

Comment: You might want to consider Rabbi Deutsch's 'Let my Nation Go' which retells the story using all the midrashim and (footnote the sources clearly). https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Yosef-Deutsch/Let-My-Nation-Go---The-Story-of-the-Exodus__p-826-2420.aspx

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90200/13438

Comment: I second @Dov in his suggestion of rabbi deutsch's book. it's very good and a must-have for your jewish library